# How to determine the matrix of $T: p(x) \longrightarrow p(x+1)$ with respect to the basis $1, x, x^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

An excercise for school is about the transformation $T: \mathbb{R}_{\leq2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\leq2}$ by $T: p(x) \longrightarrow p(x+1)$ where I have to determine the matrix $T$ with respect to the basis $B = (1, x, x^2)$. My next step is:
$$T(1)_B = (1+1)_B = (2, 0, 0)^t$$
$$T(x)_B = (x+1)_B = (1, 1, 0)^t$$
$$T(x^2)_B = (x^2+1)_B = (1, 0, 1)^t$$
so that you get the following matrix:

$$T^B_B=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, this is wrong according to the answer book, which gives the following:

$$T^B_B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

So my question is basically: where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to formally replace $x$ by $x+1$ wherever it appears.

$$1\to1,\\x\to x+1,\\x^2\to(x+1)^2.$$

And of course

$$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1.$$

---

Note that the transformation you tried is

$$p(x)\to p(x)+1,$$ which is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if we write $\;p(x)=1\;$ , then $\;p(x+1)=1\;$  again, so $\;Tp(x)=T(1)=1\;$ . In a similar way, if $\;p(x)=x^2\;$, then $\;p(x+1)=(x+1)^2\;$ , and thus $\;Tx^2=(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1\;$ , and etc.

The only one that is correct is $\;Tx=x+1\;$ .

Thus you must correct your calculations to get the matrix they want.

Answer (score 1):

Given
$p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$,
\begin{align*}
p(x+1) &= a_0 + a_1(x+1) + a_2(x+1)^2\\
p(x+1) &= (a_0 + a_1 + a_2) + (a_1 + 2a_2)x + a_2x^2
\end{align*}

From this, one can read off:
$T= \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 &1\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$, such that $T\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
a_2\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_0+a_1+a_2\\
a_1+2a_2\\
a_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$